# How to determine the right font size for android?

Tags: android, measure, text-size

I'm developing an app for android mobile devices. I'm using the AVD emulator and everything seems to be fine, but then I tested it on real device(HTC Wildfire 240x320) and the text appears so small that I can not read it. For `android:textSize` I'm using **sp** measure! I tried also to change the density of the emulator from 240 to 480 - no effect!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

It's possible that your HTC Wildfire have a user preference set to very small text.